# Problems registering Selenium nodes on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, selenium

Using Selenium Grid 2. Hub is running on the Hyper-V host and is listening to port 4444. I've confirmed this by browsing to it from a different PC, and by using `netstat -a -t -o`.

However, my guest VMs cannot connect to port 4444 on the host. They *can* connect to port 80 on the host.

Also, using IE on the host cannot connect to port 4444 on the host.

I don't think it's a firewall issue because I can connect to port 4444 (and port 80) from a different (physical) machine on the network. I can't turn the firewall off (enforced by policy), but I have added java.exe as an exception.

It doesn't appear to be a binding issue: the Selenium output shows that it's binding to 0.0.0.0, and this is shown in the netstat output as well.

Any ideas how I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: Yeah, it does sound like a firewall issue, but I don't think so. Updated the question.